# EF Core: No connection string named 'MyEntities' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a .NET 5 Web Api Project(VS 2015) used some project references(VS 2013) using entity framework 6.1.3.

When run the Web Api Project, I have got the exception "No connection string named 'MyEntities' could be found in the application config file".

this is my config:

```
{
  "webroot": "wwwroot",
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
  "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta5",
"EntityFramework": "6.1.3",
"structuremap": "3.1.6.186",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta6",
"Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta5",
"System.ServiceModel.Duplex": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
"System.ServiceModel.NetTcp": "4.0.0-beta-23019",
"System.ServiceModel.Security": "4.0.0-beta-23019"

},

"commands": {
"web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --config hosting.ini",
"ef": "EntityFramework.Commands"
},

"frameworks": {
"dnx451": {
"dependencies": {
"CuttingEdge.Conditions": "1.0.0-*",
"Quartz": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.Application": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.Finance": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.Infrastructure": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.QuartzScheduler": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.ServiceDesks": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.Utilities": "1.0.0-*",
"Project.WCFMock": "1.0.0-*"
},
"frameworkAssemblies": {
"System.ServiceModel": "4.0.0.0"
}
}
},

"publishExclude": [
"node_modules",
"bower_components",
"**.xproj",
"**.user",
"**.vspscc"
],
"exclude": [
"wwwroot",
"node_modules",
"bower_components"
]
}
```

this is my Startup.cs:

```
public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }       

        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
        {
            var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
               .AddJsonFile("config.json")
               .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

        }

        // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            var connectionString = Configuration.Get("Data:BrokerageSimulatorEntities:ConnectionString");
```

and config.json:

```
"Data": {
    "MyEntities": {
      "ConnectionString": "myConnectionString"
    },
```

Please help me!

Comment: your project.json has both EF 6.1 and EF 7 reference, please use only one i.e. in your case EF 6.1 is being used. Just keep that and remove EF 7 beta

Comment: what does your startup.cs and config.json look like?

Comment: Thanks. I have tried but that is not the problem. I have implemented the startup.cs and config.json :

Comment: Decide between `BrokerageSimulatorEntities` and `MyEntities`?

Comment: Fix your question, this clearly does not depict the accurate behavior